# Run evaluateJavascript() function sequentially using Kotlin Corutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working on a pet project where I'm trying to create a hybrid app using a `WebView`. The web platform that I run in the `WebView` sends events to the WebView/App through a `@JavascriptInterface` object. I can also *command* the web navigation by running a set of javascript functions against the web platform via the `WebView` using the `evaluateJavascript(String, (String) -> Unit)` function.

What I'm trying to achieve right now is that these *commands* that I execute through the `evaluateJavascript(String, (String) -> Unit)` function run sequentially. I might execute these commands from many different places at the same time, so I want them to run, wait for the callback from the `evaluateJavascript()` function to get called, and then execute the next command in the queue.

This is what I have in my custom `WebView` class:

```
    val scriptQueue = mutableListOf<String>()
    
    fun queueEvaluateJavascript(script: String) {
        if (webViewIsLoading) {
            scriptQueue.add(script)
        } else {
            scriptQueue.add(script)
            runScriptQueue()
        }
    }
    
    fun runScriptQueue() {
        for (script in scriptQueue) {
            evaluateJavascript(script, { })
        }
        scriptQueue.clear()
    }
```

As you can see this is a super basic approach, and I don't really account for the `evaluateJavascript()` callback. Ideally, I'd like to find a way to *flat map* each of this `evaluateJavascript()` calls so we execute one after another, but waiting for the callback to go through.

With RxJava I think I'd create an Observable and then have the `evaluateJavascript()` callback trigger the subscriber's `onNext()`. Since, I'm using Kotlin Coroutines I wanted to do something with Coroutines, so I can queue these `evaulateJavascript()` calls. But I'm not 100% sure what would be the equivalent here.

Comment: Hmm -- I've been doing some GitHub googling and this approach [here](https://github.com/AptoPayments/apto-pci-sdk-android/blob/eb4d5b31563090862318b86f1858826adfb23f85/pcisdk/src/main/java/com/aptopayments/sdk/queue/WebViewJSActionsQueue.kt) does look interesting, but they don't use Coroutines.

Comment: Looks like `evaluateJavascript` doesn't take `(String, Unit)` but `(String, () -> Unit)`, right? The second argument is the completion callback, am I correct?

Comment: @Joffrey Oh yeah, you're right, that's my bad. Let me edit that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I just checked the API, and it takes a `ValueCallback<String>`, which can probably be used with SAM conversions like a `(String) -> Unit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a nice problem to approach with coroutines.

The usual way to convert callback based APIs to suspend functions is the following:

```kotlin
suspend fun evaluateJs(script: String) = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->
    evaluateJavascript(script) { result ->
        cont.resume(result)
    }
}
```

You can then use that in combination maybe with a `Channel` (to serve as a queue) and a coroutine that processes this channel:

```kotlin
class MyWebView(context: Context) : WebView(context) {
    
    private val jsQueue = Channel<String>(BUFFERED)

    fun startJsProcessingLoopIn(scope: CoroutineScope) {
        scope.launch { 
            for (script in jsQueue) {
                evaluateJs(script)
            }
        }
    }

    // you could also make this function non-suspend if necessary by calling
    // sendBlocking (or trySend depending on coroutines version)
    suspend fun queueEvaluateJavascript(script: String) {
        jsQueue.send(script)
    }

    private suspend fun evaluateJs(script: String) = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->
        evaluateJavascript(script) { result ->
            cont.resume(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can create your own coroutine scope and make sure to tie it with some sort of lifecycle of your webview (I'm not familiar with `WebView` so I'll let you judge which kind of method is correct):

```kotlin
class MyWebView2(context: Context) : WebView(context) {

    // you can even further customize the exact thread pool used here 
    // by providing a particular dispatcher
    private val jsProcessingScope = CoroutineScope(CoroutineName("js-processing"))

    private val jsQueue = Channel<String>(BUFFERED)

    // this starts the loop right away but you can also put this in a method 
    // to start it at a more appropriate moment
    init {
        jsProcessingScope.launch {
            for (script in jsQueue) {
                evaluateJs(script)
            }
        }
    }

    // you could also make this function non-suspend if necessary by calling
    // sendBlocking (or trySend depending on coroutines version)
    suspend fun queueEvaluateJavascript(script: String) {
        jsQueue.send(script)
    }

    private suspend fun evaluateJs(script: String) = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->
        evaluateJavascript(script) { result ->
            cont.resume(result)
        }
    }

    fun someCloseOrDisposeCallback() {
        jsProcessingScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is _exactly_ what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Happy new year! Sorry, you know, I'm trying to add a new piece of functionality on top of this JS queue, and that is the ability to ditch duplicate JS commands. I'm trying to make this JS queue smart enough so if I ever call the `queueEvaluateJavascript` with the same script commands, only the last one will go through. Any ideas or any links about how we can remove duplicate elements stored within a buffered channel? Thanks!